# Elasticsearch and nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch I index documents like this:

```
{
    "title": "hello world",
    "media": [{"type": "image"}, {"type": "audio"}]
}
```

The `media` property is a nested document, and I'm trying to do the following queries:

- return all documents matching a specific query, and filter down the media documents in those documents by a separate queries (example: all documents, but only return the media type "image"). So far I have only managed to only return documents with media of that type, excluding all documents without that media.
- return all documents having at least x items in media of type "image"
- limit the amount of media documents are returned

Are these things possible or do I have to enhance these queries outside elasticsearch?

Comment: look at parent child relation instead of nested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398664/elasticsearch-query-to-filter-and-aggregate-on-nested-object-term/44408392#44408392

Comment: I have looked at that as well, while that gives me some of the features I need, it will also give me some problems: I need to be able to replace all children in one go. It seems that it is better for my use case to don't use nested of parent-child at all, and keep track of the counts separately (while updating the media putting extra properties), and filtering the media manually in code instead of with elasticsearch.