# ElasticSearch - Query to filter and aggregate on nested object term

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have nested objects in my elastic search index of the following type

```
 "_source": {
           "NAME": "MNQ",
           "LAST_MOD_DATE": 1373587200000,
           "ACTIVE_FL": "Y",
           "ID": "1008",
           "USER": [
              {
                 "USR_ID": 499,
                 "STATUS": "INACTV",
                 "NAME": "ABC"
              },
              {
                 "USR_ID": 53,
                 "STATUS": "ACTV",
                 "NAME": "XYZ"
              }
            ]
        }
```

And I have following use cases for querying the index:

- Get all active users for a particular id. Eg: I want to get users that are active for id `1008` which in this case would be user `XYZ`
- Get all active users. Eg: I perform a match_all query and I wan to aggregate on term `USER.NAME` but it should only return me the names of active users.

I am having trouble performing these nested operations as search for active status will return a record which has even one of the users as active. I am unable to specifically filter out inactive users. Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

since you are always interested in fetching the users then in that case [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) relationship will do better than nested documents type for users. As with nested type the response will have unnecessary payload with inner_hits for elastic.

As the provide better navigation and more flexible queries for nested association then nested type.

Also in mappings you may have to select type to `keyword` or create a custom analyzer to retain the case as you are searching as case sensitive search.

**Mappings for parent-child relationship**

```
PUT parent_child_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "parent_document": {
            "properties": {
                "NAME": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "parent_document"
            },
            "properties": {
                "USER_ID": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "STATUS": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "NAME": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index parent child documents**

```
POST parent_child_index/parent_document
{
    "NAME": "MNQ",
    "LAST_MOD_DATE": 1373587200000,
    "ACTIVE_FL": "Y",
    "ID": "1008"
}


POST parent_child_index/user?parent=AVyBzQXmp_hWdUR22wGr
{
    "USR_ID": 53,
    "STATUS": "ACTV",
    "NAME": "XYZ"
}
```

**Query**

```
POST parent_child_index/user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "has_parent": {
                        "parent_type": "parent_document",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [{
                                    "term": {
                                        "ID": {
                                            "value": "1008"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "STATUS": {
                            "value": "ACTV"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

POST parent_child_index/user/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "active_users": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "STATUS": "ACTV"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "user_name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "NAME",
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed response. It isn't easy to implement in my current setup and has raised another issue which I have detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423284/logstash-split-incoming-nested-message-into-a-parent-child-model